# Split rows in multiple rows based on variable time condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, rows

I have shifts that work like this:

```
  Shift horaIni     horaFin
0   A   00:00:00    08:00:00
1   B   08:00:00    16:00:00
2   C   16:00:00    23:59:59
```

Dataframe below is my input and I need to split a row according to the shifts. So if a row has an INITRA in shift A on day 1 and a FINTRA in shift C on day 3 I need to split that in multiple rows having all shifts and days. All other colum values of that row are repeated.

***FOCUS ON ROW 1 (index 0)***

```
   col1 col2       INITRA               FINTRA     col3 col4 col5
0   C2  Y5  2021-02-15 22:07:00 2021-02-17 05:26:42 AA  AL  111871
1   X12 Y1  2021-02-15 22:00:36 2021-02-15 22:02:40 AA  AL  111863
2   S44 S1  2021-02-15 21:30:39 2021-02-15 21:44:51 AA  AL  111863
3   Z1  J7  2021-02-15 21:26:28 2021-02-15 21:28:00 AA  AL  111863
4   O9  H5  2021-02-15 21:14:29 2021-02-15 21:15:40 AA  AL  111863
5   O7  H8  2021-02-15 20:45:31 2021-02-15 20:46:39 AA  AL  111863
6   H8  Y5  2021-02-15 20:37:05 2021-02-15 20:38:10 AA  AL  111863
7   C2  Q1  2021-02-15 20:15:49 2021-02-15 20:27:22 AA  AL  111863
```

Expected result below

```
  col1 col2 col3 col4  col5  dateIni      dateFin   horaIni      horaFin  Shift
0   C2  Y5  AA  AL  111871  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  22:07:00    23:59:59    C
1   C2  Y5  AA  AL  111871  2021-02-16  2021-02-16  00:00:00    08:00:00    A
2   C2  Y5  AA  AL  111871  2021-02-16  2021-02-16  08:00:00    16:00:00    B
3   C2  Y5  AA  AL  111871  2021-02-16  2021-02-16  16:00:00    23:59:59    C
4   C2  Y5  AA  AL  111871  2021-02-17  2021-02-17  00:00:00    05:26:42    A
5   X12 Y1  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  22:00:36    22:02:40    C
6   S44 S1  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  21:30:39    21:44:51    C
7   Z1  J7  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  21:26:28    21:28:00    C
8   O9  H5  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  21:14:29    21:15:40    C
9   O7  H8  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  20:45:31    20:46:39    C
10  H8  Y5  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  20:37:05    20:38:10    C
11  C2  Q1  AA  AL  111863  2021-02-15  2021-02-15  20:15:49    20:27:22    C
```

I was able to solve the problem for INITRA and FINTRA happening on consecutive shifts on the same day but when I have a greater difference I cant seem to solve it. My database has hundreds of thousands of rows.

I've been stuck on this for a while now. I appreciate any help. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
from pprint import pprint
initra = ['2021-02-15 22:07:00','2021-02-15 22:00:36']
fintra = ['2021-02-17 05:26:42','2021-02-15 22:02:40']

dateIni = [t[:-9] for t in initra]
horaIni = [t[11:] for t in initra]
dateFin = [t[:-9] for t in fintra]
horaFin = [t[11:] for t in fintra]

updatedDatabase = [[],[],[],[],[]]

def generate_database(enterdate,exitdate,entertime,exittime,Shift):
    updatedDatabase[0].append(enterdate)
    updatedDatabase[1].append(exitdate) 
    updatedDatabase[2].append(entertime)
    updatedDatabase[3].append(exittime) 
    updatedDatabase[4].append(Shift)

def generate_shift(dateIni,dateFin,horaIni,horaFin):
    for index,elem in enumerate(dateIni):
        enterdate = dateIni[index]
        exitdate = dateFin[index]
        entertime = horaIni[index]
        exittime = horaFin[index]
        count = abs(int(dateIni[index][8:]) - int(dateFin[index][8:]))
        count = count if count != 0 else 1
        for h in range(3*count):

            if enterdate == exitdate: 
                if int(entertime[:-6]) >= 0 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 8:
                    if int(exittime[:-6]) > 8:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'08:00:00','A')
                        entertime = '08:00:00'
                    else:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,exittime,'A')
                        break

                elif int(entertime[:-6]) >= 8 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 16:
                    if int(exittime[:-6])> 16:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'16:00:00','B')
                        entertime = '16:00:00'
                    else:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,exittime,'B')
                        break
                elif int(entertime[:-6]) >= 16 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 24:
                    if int(exittime[:-6])> 24:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'16:00:00','B')
                        entertime = exittime
                    else:
                        generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,exittime,'B')
                        break

            else:
                if int(entertime[:-6]) >= 0 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 8:
                    generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'08:00:00','A')
                    entertime = '08:00:00'

                elif int(entertime[:-6]) >= 8 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 16:
                    generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'16:00:00','B')
                    entertime = '16:00:00'

                elif int(entertime[:-6]) >= 16 and int(entertime[:-6]) < 24:
                    generate_database(enterdate,enterdate,entertime,'23:59:59','C')
                    x = str(int(enterdate.replace('-','')) + 1)
                    enterdate = x[:-4]+'-'+x[4:-2]+'-'+x[6:]
                    entertime = '00:00:00'


generate_shift(dateIni,dateFin,horaIni,horaFin)

for i in range(len(updatedDatabase[0])):
    print(updatedDatabase[0][i],updatedDatabase[1][i],updatedDatabase[2][i],updatedDatabase[3][i],updatedDatabase[4][i])
```

Comment: you just assigned the shift considering the the inverval of INITRA and FINTRA. What I need is to split a row in multiple rows when my INITRA and FINTRA go through multiple shifts.

Comment: well this will work :), Now you just have to update database to your end

Comment: that almost worked but I was able to built something with your idea. Thank you so much for your help.

Just an observation: Instead of doing this:

                    x = str(int(enterdate.replace('-','')) + 1)
                    enterdate = x[:-4]+'-'+x[4:-2]+'-'+x[6:]

Its better to use .datetime + timedelta because it fixes the problem when you go over a month.

Thanks again for the help